# How to enable Bluetooth at startup on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I am using a Bluetooth mouse and Bluetooth speakers for my laptop. The problem is that when the system boots up, the Bluetooth is not turned on and I have to turn it on manually every time.

Is there any way to set Bluetooth to turn on during boot time? I looked at answers here but none of them is working.

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I tried but it is no use. Still after every reboot I have to manually enable BT. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check that "AutoEnable=true" is set here /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Comment: @LarsAamo I have `AutoEnable=true` set, but this has no effect.. any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try to add bluetoothctl to cron as startup script.
@reboot bluetoothctl power on

Answer (score 0):

`AutoEnable=true` in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf solved the Problem in Ubuntu 23.10.
Bluetooth is always deactivated on startup and can be activated via the system menu top right.

This does not persist across reboots, unfortunately.